# Driver not showing up in menuconfig Yocto

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, kernel-modules, yocto

For my project I would like to import the ath10k driver, but when I run menuconfig only ath9k shows up.

[image: Device Drivers/Network device support/Wireless LAN]

Is there any way to import it?

Comment: Where did you find the ath10k driver? Did you look in it to see if there were instructions?

Comment: Hi! what do you mean by where did I find the ath10k driver? It is included in yocto's distribution